# Performance of DOM manipulation for Responsive Web Design

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, responsive-design, dom-manipulation

I want to ask you, is it a good idea to use jQuery's `append()` method (and other similar methods like `prepend()`, `remove()`) for DOM manipulations to make the website responsive? How does it affect performance?

## Example:

I have a menu (very big multilevel menu with hundreds of links) which is displayed at the top of the page on desktop. But it needs to be displayed in completely different place on mobile devices.

### Solution 1:

Probably the simplest way to achieve this would be to include the menu more than once and just hide one menu with `display: none;` and show the other one with `display: block;` using **CSS media queries**:

```
<div id="menu-desktop-container">
    <div class="menu">...</div>
</div>

<!-- ...Here's some other HTML between both positions of the menus -->

<div id="menu-mobile-container">
    <div class="menu">...</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for this:

```
#menu-desktop-container { display: block; }
#menu-mobile-container { display: none; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    #menu-desktop-container { display: none; }
    #menu-mobile-container { display: block; }
}
```

But it has many drawbacks. E.g. the menu is really big so including it twice will make the page almost two times bigger. This will affect performance and increase load time (especially on mobile devices with slower connection). Also, it's probably very bad for SEO, all links are duplicated.

### Solution 2:

Other solution is to include the menu only once, and move it to proper container with jQuery's `append()` method. Here's the HTML markup (now it's much simpler as the menu is not duplicated):

```
<div id="menu-desktop-container">
    <div id="menu">...</div>
</div>

<!-- ...Here's some other HTML between both positions of the menus -->

<div id="menu-mobile-container"></div>
```

Then if the screen is narrow, I can move the menu to the mobile container using jQuery:

```
$("#menu-mobile-container").append( $("#menu") );
```

And if the screen is wide, I can move the menu back to the default desktop container:

```
$("#menu-desktop-container").append( $("#menu") );
```

I like the solution with `append()` method much more, but I have some concerns:

### Questions

1. How does it affect performance?
2. Will it work correct on mobile devices?
3. Will it work in all browsers?
4. Will it work in old versions of Internet Explorer?
5. Are there any other drawbacks which I should be aware of before I start using this method?

Comment: It's important to remember that most of the people will not keep resizing the page for fun... at least after the first time they do it. If that's the case, it might be better to go with the js way since the moving may never occur. If you expect people to keep resizing all the time then it is probably better just to include the menu with css to begin with. Your issue more or less comes from bad design in my opinion. The answer might even be an opinion, I am not sure if there is a best way to do this. A design like this should be revised assuming you can't do it with pure css.

Comment: Why does "different place" necessarily mean "different location in the DOM"?

Comment: 1) Moving just one DOM node to another position is relatively “cheap”. 2) – 4) – please do your own research on those points.

Comment: @Bergi I can't change the position of that element using just the CSS (design doesn't let me do this), so the only option is moving the menu or duplicate the menu.

Comment: @CBroe a) I asked my questions incorrectly. I meant: "are there any known issues with this method on mobile devices or old browsers"? I've checked most obvious cases, like iPad, Android etc. All seems to work fine. b) What tools it is best to use to check how much `append()` affects performance? @Huangism Design can't be changed so I need to just pick the best solution. It will not be resized often (user just open the site on desktop or mobile and usually don't resize it).

Comment: "*How does it affect performance?*" - depends on the implementation, especially whether you continuously measure the screen width, but in general a single `append()` operation has nearly zero cost.

Comment: @Bergi Checking if screen was resized will not be a problem, I use deferred `resize` event (using `setTimeout()`) so it is quite effective. What is the best method to measure how all of this affect performance of the site? I don't have much experience with JS.

Comment: Use your site with the feature switched off. Then switch it on, and try again. If the site feels slower, investigate the why. Of course doing something will always take longer than doing nothing, but measuring milliseconds is rather pointless here.

Comment: And these days, and for quite some time (since 2011) mobile first is recommended, it is less css for the smaller devices you just design for mobile and then in the min-width start adding the floats and styles for larger viewports.

Comment: If you do mobile first, you can usually put the menu in the correct place on mobile and through the use of absolute positioning in the min-width, get it to show up below the logo or whatever. Min-width is much better, I only use clone when I want to use a different script on mobile, such as a drill down menu since a larger menu is annoying on small devices

Comment: @BootstrapThemer Thanks but if absolute positioning was an option I wouldn't ask this question. Sniffing user agent or device also doesn't seem to be a good option. I only asked about how manipulations affect performance and how to measure it.

Answer (score 1):

These two use cases are very different in terms of performance so there is no measurement to compare the two.

Both have implications but the `.append` method has almost none in this case. Not many people would resize the browser over and over and unless you need to do the appending on unconventional breakpoints, no mobile device will probably trigger this on orientation change either.

The only thing you can really measure is the performance cost of various jQuery methods [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-jquery-append-vs-jquery-prepend).

Increasing the number of DOM nodes and using CSS to hide them will probably be the worst solution. Especially on mobile devices where you should keep DOM node depth to a minimum.

The only real performance issue you need to be aware of for both these implementations is [reflows](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) and repaints where DOM node depth and count matter. Although the duplicate menu you have is `display: none;` which stops it reflowing I still believe it can create perf issues with rendering. I also found [this article](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) interesting.